# Can AWS Cognito cross region? Any workaround if not?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I've followed the [instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/s3.html) for uploading file to S3 in US region and succeed, with AWS SDK in Unity.

Now, I want to do the same to HK (ap-east-1), but I found that there's no Cognito available in HK region yet. Using the Cognite from US region seems give me an access deny.

[image]

Is there a workaround? I think I can create a IAM user but the Unity SDK only take [Cognite pool ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/setup-unity.html#step-3-obtain-the-identity-pool-id-using-amazon-cognito)...

Comment: no one.........?

Comment: my suggestion is create an s3 bucket in region where your cognito is there and enable cross region replication to s3 bucket in your desired region @richard